# How to update a FITS file header using FitsIO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fits

I am currently trying to modify the header of a FITS file. More specifically, I want to append new keywords to it. I work with FitsIO for python, in its version 0.9.11.

During some data processing, my program creates new FITS files and updates both their content and header. I used to work with Astropy but this is not an option anymore, so I'm falling back to FitsIO, which is quite a challenge for me.

Content update/overwrite is fairly straightforward, but I have trouble with the header modification. To isolate my issues, and find the correct procedure (the documentation was not very helpful), I created a small program that only test how to write the header.

As an input data, I use a FITSHDR object containing the following stuff:

```
update_data = fitsio.FITSHDR([
"IVAL    =                   36 / integer value           ",
"SHORTS  = 'hello w'                                      ",
"DBL     =                 1.25                           ",
"CDELT1  =                 0.00333333333333               "])
```

And here are the tested functions:

```
def write_hdu_1(data, fits_file):
    with fitsio.FITS(fits_file, 'rw', clobber=True) as fits:
        fits[extension].write_keys(data)
```

**RESULT**: deletes the END card, corrupting the HDU.

```
def write_hdu_2(data, fits_file):
   with fitsio.FITS(fits_file, 'rw', clobber=True) as fits:
       for key in data.keys():
           fits[extension].write_key(key, data.get(key))
```

**RESULT**: deletes the END card, corrupting the HDU.

```py
def write_hdu_3(fits_file):
    with fitsio.FITS(fits_file, 'rw', clobber=True) as fits:
        keydict = { 'name':'test', 'value':35, 'comment':'keydict test'}
        fits[-1].write_key(**keydict)
```

**RESULT**:

```
File "test_fitsio.py", line 26, in write_hdu_3
    fits[-1].write_key(**keydict)
TypeError: write_key() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Out of desperation, I finally added the "END" card manually, like that:

```py
def write_hdu(self, header_content):
    self.fits[extension].write_keys(header_content)
    self.fits[extension].write_key('END', '')
```

But, then, the END card was then padded with spaces, which was not properly recognized by the other libraries I'm using.

So, do you have any hindsight in how to add/update the header keywords, with python FitsIO, and without losing the "END" card in the process?

Thanks!

Comment: "I used to work with Astropy but this is not an option anymore, so I'm falling back to FitsIO" Why would it not be an option? `astropy.fits.io` is generally better when it comes to manipulating headers. Whereas in some cases `fitsio` will have better performance for manipulating large data files. No reason you can't use both in different contexts.

Comment: The Astropy.fits version used in my project is handling poorly the files larger than the RAM size, which is my case. And, as a matter of preference, I really don't like having more than one library in a program, dedicated to the same purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `clobber` option when you open your file and the header edition will works. The `clobber` option is made to remove any existing file before opening it see the [docstring](https://github.com/esheldon/fitsio/blob/master/fitsio/fitslib.py#L343) and the [code](https://github.com/esheldon/fitsio/blob/master/fitsio/fitslib.py#L401) implementation.

On my side this works like a charm for fitsio 0.9.11 in Python3:

```
with fitsio.FITS('test.fits', 'rw') as ff:
    ff[-1].write_key('KEY', 'key value', 'my comment')
```

On the other hand using the same code on an existing file to append a keyword in a given HDU header erase the file from disk if you use the `clobber` option.

```
$ du -sh test.fits                                                                                           
308K    test.fits
$ python3 -c "import fitsio; ff = fitsio.FITS('test.fits', 'rw', clobber=True); ff[-1].write_key('KEY', 'key value', 'my comment')"
$ du -sh test.fits                                                                                  
4.0K    test.fits
$ cat test.fits
KEY     = 'key value'          / my comment                                     END
```

This is a quiete strange result but fitsio append the `END` keyword but on an empty file which if not a valid FITS file.